# Python, int() argument must be a string error

Tags: python

My code should read each row in the matrix and convert it to a row of numbers in my distance matrix:

```
for i in range(dim):
   row = []
   for j in range(dim):
        line = f.readline()
        words = line.split()
        row.append(int(words))

distances.append(row)
```

But it gets this error everytime I try to run it:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

I don't know what's causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the traceback? `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'` and `words` is of what type?

Comment: Show your `dim` values

Answer (score 0):

As per error code - `words` is a `list` object - try passing `list[index]` to `int()` calls, not the whole list at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function like this:

```
row.append(map(lambda item: int(item)), words)
```

Comment: `map(int, words)`

Comment: That works too, but the one I wrote is more understandable.

Comment: Disagree, using `lambda` is unnecessary and hurts performance

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what's causing this. Any ideas?

The error message is quite clear:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

and indeed:

```
 words = line.split()
 row.append(int(words))
```

`str.split()` returns a `list`.

I strongly suggest [you read this and put it into practice](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) instead of posting question about such a trivial problem.

Comment: Rude answer to a question from a novice coder trying to learn.

Comment: @osprey learning how to solve this kind of issues IS the most important skill for a novice. Sometimes the error message is quite cryptic and a novice will indeed need help to make sense of it, but the above is about as clear and explicit as possible.

Answer (score -1):

In your words you probably have a list object. (`['word1', 'word2']`) etc.
You have to call the `int()` method on each occurence in the list.

Change your line `row.append(int(words))` by

```
[row.append(int(word)) for word in words]
```

Assuming all the words are strings that can be converted to integers of course.

Comment: using a list expression for side effects is very bad practice (and a huge waste of resources).

Comment: I've always been told that list comprehensions are faster than regular `for loops`. Could you comment (or edit in the response) what the recommended pythonic way would be to solve this? Generators for large data?

Comment: use `list.extend` with a generator expression (=> `row.extend(int(word)) for word in words)`). Creating dozens of lists of `None` only to discard them defeats the benefices from the list comp optimizations.